How to use sensitive envs so it works for Expo Go
I was wondering what the best approach is to set sensitive environment variables and still use Expo Go to develop my App. Because like to use the tools in the App to debug my code.
First and the easiest approach is to add the prefix EXPO_PUBLIC_X, but this will only safe the environment variables in plain text, so this is no option for me.
Secondly I found something called react-native-dotenv but this completely ruins your build. To fix this you have to remove this package and also something called babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables and delete your package-lock.json and use the command npm start --clear
And lastly I found out about Expo Secrets. But I don't know how to integrate them in my code and if it is possible to use the secrets when building for Expo Go and not with Expos service called EAS.

I use react-native-dotenv with mix of EXPO_PUBLIC_* built-in env management and it works very well for me.
Firstly. I wonder what kind of data you want to store. If some configuration of app.config.js is in .env file your build might not start or it might start with incorrect values without any warning. (Some configurations cannot be added dynamically.)
To successfully run EAS builds you have to add .easignore file and copy the contents from .gitignore expect line responsible for ignoring .env file. Normally, if you don't have this file, EAS ignores all your files \ directories so your .env file will be ignored on build startup. .easignore have higher priority over .gitignore so your env variables will not be ignored.

Because your EAS Build job runs on a remote server, these .env files might not be available. For instance, .env files are excluded from your uploaded project if they are listed in .gitignore or not committed to your local version control system

Everything you have to know is in (Remember to check article references.):

Expo Dev - article about enviroment variables

I also found this helpful:

Expo App Config

Important

Everything stored in env variables is still visible in plain text on client side.
EAS Secrets can be misleading, they don't come with additional security.


EAS Secrets do not provide any additional security for values that you end up embedding in your application itself, such as an AWS access key or other private keys.

So in summary. For me, the best approach is to use mix of EXPO_PUBLiC_* and react-native-dotenv.
EDIT:

To fix this you have to remove this package and also something called babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables and delete your package-lock.json and use the command npm start --clear

Can you tell me how it ruins your build and what steps you follow to configure react-native-dotenv?

I installed the react-native-dotenv and configured it in the babel.config.js. After i restarted my simulator and my application. After compiling and opening Expo Go a screen popped up "Welcome to Expo" large text with a prompt to create a file in "app" dir.

I would be nice if you could provide your babel config, maybe something is missing. You can check minimal working example in minimal babel config for expo apps

You can check in docs if your are using EXPO_PUBLIC_* you can safely delete
babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables. Notice that react-native-dotenv for Expo do not require this plugin.

Thanks for your comments, but i decided to leave those variables out of my mobile application and use my backend to resolve those problems. Because it is the safest way to do this. Still all you said is true so I will upvote your answer

Storing sensitive info on backed is always the best :)
